# How do I load images in android app from spring boot application?

Tags: android, hibernate, spring-boot, postgresql-9.3

I'm having issue with loading multiple images from database to android application using spring boot application?

i'm able to save images in my db but i don't know how do i load the images from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in two way :

Buffer read from BLOB wrap in `InputStream` so you will have `InputStream` which will point to `BLOB` data

Save `BLOB` data to temporary file open it as `FileInputStream` - so in the end you'll again have stream over image data

in both cases you can easily convert `InputStream` to `bitmat` data in a way:

```
InputStream is; //stream pointing to your blob or file
//...

imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
```